# Order element with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by

I would like to order my groups with 2 variables (notifications(integer) & priority(integer[1, 2, 3])).

That's the order I want to achieve :

```
1.Group with notifications 
  a.Group with priority(1)
  b.Group with priority(2)
2. Group without notifications 
  a.Group with priority(1)
  b.Group with priority(2)
  c.Group with priority(3)
```

What do you think is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to split your order differently. For me the easiest way to order your groups it's like this :

```
1. Group notified without priority(3) 
2. Group not notified without priority(3) # We also add without priority in this step to avoid duplication
3. Group With the less priority
```

After that, you build some scope, and order by default:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope {order(priority: asc)} 

  scope :notified, -> { where.not(notifications: 0, priority: 3) }
  scope :not_notified, -> { where(notifications: 0).where.not(priority: 3) }
  scope :not_important, -> { where(priority: 3) }

end
```

And finally, you render your groups like this:

```
<% @groups = Group.all %>

<% @groups.notified.each do |group| %>
  Group notified 
<% end %>

<% @groups.not_notified.each do |group| %>
  Group not notified 
<% end %>

<% @groups.not_important.each do |group| %>
  Group not important 
<% end %>
```